# Coverity reference function inputs for a custom checker

Tags: c++, coverity-prevent

Is there a simple way to take the general arguments of a function (Pointer, Array, Integer) and get the values backing the expression, when writing a custom checker? As in, I match against a function such as:

```
Pointer p;

Integer i;

CallSite f("func");

if(MATCH( f(p,i) ))
   //get function arguments
```

Is there a simple way of getting the values backing p and i? Thanks.

**Language is C++ to make a custom checker

Comment: Please add the language which you are using.

Comment: Coverity SDK the poster is referring to, at least in the current version, only supports C/C++ analysis, so the language is (subtly) implicit in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get run-time value from these variables statically.

Maybe it's more accurate to say that this is beyond the scope of what a simple static analysis checker can do.

The exception would be if you are passing a literal value or constant.